# deslocar todas as linhas de uma matriz para baixo

Tags: c, array, matriz, for, lógica

Olá, Eu estou com um problema na hora de ordenar as linhas de uma matriz. Eu criei um programa que deve "descer as linhas de uma matriz. A ultima linha vai para a primeira e as outras linhas descem. Exemplo:

```
   2 3        2 3       4 3
   2 1    =   4 3    =  2 3
   4 3        2 1       2 1
```

O problema é o programa também inverte as colunas da matriz. Como faz para que só as linhas sejam modificadas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define n 3
#define m 2 
int main()
{
    int matriz[n][m]={{2,3}, {2,1}, {4,3}}, soma, aux, desce=1, vetor[n*m], index=0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
        {   
            printf(" matriz antes %d", matriz[i][j]);
            
        }
            printf(" \n");
    }
         
    printf("\n");
    
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            
            mat[index++]=matriz[i][j];
            
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<index - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i + 1; j<index; j++)
        {
            aux=mat[i];
             mat[i]=mat[j];
             mat[j]=aux;
    
        }

    }
    
    index=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            matriz[i][j]=mat[index++];
            
        }
    }
         
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
        { 
            printf(" matriz depois %d", matriz[i][j]);
            
        }
             printf("\n");
    }
    
   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

no Decorrer do seu còdigo a variàvel "matriz" mudou de nome , e você sò precisa de dois loop's , sendo um para pegar os nùmeros da primeira linha da matriz e guarda los no vetor , e outro para colocar esses mesmos nùmeros na ùltima linha da matriz .